# Windows taskbar button widths

Tags: windows, taskbar

How can I change the Taskbar Button widths in Windows systems (esp. for XP and Vista)? I like to make the buttons narrower so that I can see only the icon of the related application window. Is it possible for all versions of Windows operating systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update: `www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm` stands broken at this time -- I've 'unplugged' the links to be safe]

At this `Registry Edits for Windows XP "Tweaks and Tips" site XP page`(`www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm`),
There are two VB Scripts to tweak the size (besides a lot of other tweaks).

Its VB Script, so you can download it, look at it, change it -- have fun.
<sup>Not sure if it will work for Vista too.</sup>

VBScript refs: `Decrease the Size of Taskbar Buttons`(`www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/taskbaricons.vbs`
) and `Undo`(`www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/taskbariconsundo.vbs`).

There is also a [**Windows 7** reference](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/21233-taskbar-change-icon-button-width-size.html).

Comment: Reading that script (as of today) it seems to contains ads. It does not seem to do anything and it's not VB at all. I could not easily determine it to be safe. I decided not to run it.

Comment: @usr thanks for pointing that out! I've disabled the links in my answer. Have not got around searching for a replacement yet.