# Little size of windows on taskbar. How to fix it?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

How to change it to normal size?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the taskbar and select *Properties*. Uncheck the mark near "Use small icons" and click OK. That's all.

[image]

If you are talking about the **taskbar button widths**, you should see the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/54783/windows-taskbar-button-widths).

To undo the resizing of taskbar icons, you can use [this VB script](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/regs_edits/taskbariconsundo.vbs). It's safe and simply changes the value of `MinWidth` in the related registry path. For convenience, I'm copying the script here:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WSHShell, n, p, itemtype, MyBox

Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
p = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\"
p = p & "MinWidth"
itemtype = "REG_SZ"
n = "-2310"

WSHShell.RegWrite p, n, itemtype

MyBox = MsgBox("You must reboot for the changes to take effect.", vbOKOnly,"Done")
```

Comment: Thanx, but I use Windows XP, and... it seems ti me that there isn't that option...

Comment: Please see the last line in my answer (link to another question).

Comment: Thanx, but I'm afraid to use any scripts... Is it so difficult to fix it.. I thought that I just pushed something wrong... Thanx anyway.

Comment: @Daria: Please see my edit. I hope that helps. If you want to do it manually, just go to the related registry path and delete `MinWidth` key.

Comment: @Daria: Don't worry about the script.  If you create a System Restore point, you can rollback any changes it makes.

Comment: Finally!! Thank you very very much! It helps!

Comment: @Daria: You're more than welcome.