# How to get a thin side pinned taskbar with small icons

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

**What I try to accomplish**

Reduce size/width of a left pinned taskbar using small icons

**What have I tried**

When I use my taskbar on the bottom and configure it to use small icons, the height used by the taskbar gets reduced by halve. If I try to pin the taskbar to the left side of the screen, the same approach does not work.

I have read about some tricks in windows xp using some [script](https://superuser.com/questions/316660/little-size-of-windows-on-taskbar-how-to-fix-it) to reduce the size of the taskbar. This required to remove the windows logo and clock from the taskbar. I have reduced both but this doesn't affect the size of the taskbar.

**My question**

Is there some registry entry where I could set the width of my taskbar (pinned to the left side)? Or is there some tool to accomplish this? I am using Windows 8.1.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Download and install the tool "7+ Taskbar Tweaker". Then when running it go to advanced settings which are hidden in the try icon. In the advanced settings you can set the min widht from 0 to 1. Restart your computer. Now you can reduce the size of your sidebar to a minimum.